# A discrete space of cardinality $\aleph_0$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How does a discrete space of cardinality $\aleph_0$ looks like? On finite sets I always get finite discrete spaces, countable sets (i.e. sets of cardinality $\aleph_0$) yields spaces of cardinality $> \aleph_0$, cause $2^{\mathbb N}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Note that the cardinality of a topological space is the cardinality of the underlying set, not that of the topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the natural numbers with the standard topology (induced by the order, or from $\Bbb R$). Or it looks like $\Bbb Z$ as well.

Or any infinite subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Note that the cardinality of the space is the cardinality of the underlying set, not the cardinality of the topology itself. It is true, though, that if $X$ is infinite and $(X,\tau)$ is discrete then $\tau$ is uncountable. But we still say that the topological space is countable in the case where $X$ is countable.

Comment: And could this be written as subsets of a base sets, because that is the way my textbook defines a discrete space, i.e. $(X, \tau)$ is a discrete space iff $\tau = 2^{X}$?

Comment: @Stefan: There is a difference between the cardinality of the space and the cardinality of the topology. Yes, the discrete topology is uncountable whenever $X$ is infinite, but the space itself is still countable.

Answer (score 1):

The discrete spaces are the most easiest to construct, since the topology is always the powerset. Namely, if you have to construct a discrete space with cardinality $\kappa$, pick up any set $A$ which has such cardinality and endow it with the discrete topology $2^A$.